# Adding items of a treeview to a textbox in WPF by clicking on them

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview and I want to add the treeviewitems to textbox by clicking on them in WPF.

Comment: private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = treeView1.content;
        }

Comment: I don't know, it isn't correct but i don't know what can i use instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a MouseLeftButtonDown event handler to each TreeViewItem and use the sender parameter to extract the TreeViewItem's content.  You can even use a Style to make sure that the event handler gets attached.

```
<TreeView>
<TreeView.Resources>
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
<EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseRightButtonDown">
</EventSetter>
</Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeViewItem Header="Root">
<TreeViewItem Header="Child 1">
<TreeViewItem Header="Grandchild 1"/>
<TreeViewItem Header="Grandchild 2"/>
</TreeViewItem>
<TreeViewItem Header="Child 2">
<TreeViewItem Header="Grandchild 3"/>
<TreeViewItem Header="Grandchild 4"/>
</TreeViewItem>
</TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```